# PhpStorm: how to go back after a Ctrl+B?

Tags: phpstorm

Can someone tell me if there is a shortcut in PhpStorm that allows to go back to the file I was before I press `Ctrl+B` shortcut?

> Edit: `Ctrl+B` may be the key shortcut for navigating to the declaration of a variable (*the part of the code that states what `$var` is set to*).

Comment: What does Ctrl-B do?

Comment: @IMSoP haha, whatever you want once you've set it in the controls menu `;-)`. Except make coffee, PHPStorm still can't make a good cup of coffee (*even after installing CoffeeScript*)

Comment: to be honest I never use Ctrl+B it's always just easier clicking on the `$var`

Comment: in Mac: `Command + [`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, there is shortcut for that: `ALT + left` (Navigate -> Back)

Comment: hahahaha amusingly enough this key combination causes my graphics driver (intel) to rotate my desktop 90degrees left!!

Comment: That seems wrong to me, at least in PhpStorm 2017.1.4. `Alt + Left` just switches to the tab on the left of the current one. To navigate to the previous location it's `Ctrl + Alt + Left`.

Answer (score 2):

The command `Back` from the `Navigate` menu should do what you need. On OSX, using the default keymap, its shortcut is <kbd>Alt-Cmd-Left</kbd>.